# Build a list of the names of applicants who have scores strictly greater than the given threshold

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting the logic down for adding values that are only greater than the score threshold.

I've tried multiple things like nested if statements and while loops but I can't seem to get it down. I have to return a list of names of students whose scores are all above a certain threshold.

```
type hereimport java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ExampleMap {

  /**
   * Return a list of "high scoring" students --- High scoring students are
   * students who have all grades strictly greater than the given threshold.
   *
   * @param scoresByApplicantName A map of applicant names to applicant scores
   * @param scoreThreshold        The score threshold
   * @return The list of high-scoring applicant names
   */
  public static List<String> highScoringStudents(Map<String, List<CourseGrade>> scoresByApplicantName, int scoreThreshold) {

    List<String> highScoringStudents = new LinkedList<>();

    /*
     * Build a list of the names of applicants who have scores strictly greater than
     * the given threshold.
     */
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<CourseGrade>> current : scoresByApplicantName.entrySet()) {
      List<CourseGrade> course_grades = current.getValue();
      for (CourseGrade courses : course_grades) {
        if (courses.getScore() > scoreThreshold) {
          highScoringStudents.add(current.getKey());
        }
      }
    }
    return highScoringStudents;
  }
}
```

the course grade class

```
/*
 * This file should remain unchanged.
 */
public class CourseGrade {
  private String courseName;
  private int score; 

  /**
   * This is a constructor. It creates a new CourseGrade with the specified scores.
   * @param courseName
   * @param score 
   */
  public CourseGrade(String courseName, int score) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.score = score;
  }

  public String getCourseName() {
    return this.courseName;
  }

  public int getScore() {
    return this.score;
  }
}
```

test to be ran

```
  @Test
   public void testExampleMap1()
   {
      Map<String, List<CourseGrade>> courseListsByStudent = new HashMap<>();
      courseListsByStudent.put("Julie",
         Arrays.asList(
            new CourseGrade("CPE 123", 89),
            new CourseGrade("CPE 101", 90),
            new CourseGrade("CPE 202", 99),
            new CourseGrade("CPE 203", 100),
            new CourseGrade("CPE 225", 89)));
      courseListsByStudent.put("Paul",
         Arrays.asList(
            new CourseGrade("CPE 101", 86),
            new CourseGrade("CPE 202", 80),
            new CourseGrade("CPE 203", 76),
            new CourseGrade("CPE 225", 80)));
      courseListsByStudent.put("Zoe",
         Arrays.asList(
            new CourseGrade("CPE 123", 99),
            new CourseGrade("CPE 203", 91),
            new CourseGrade("CPE 471", 86),
            new CourseGrade("CPE 473", 90),
            new CourseGrade("CPE 476", 99),
            new CourseGrade("CPE 572", 100)));

      List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("Julie", "Zoe");

      /*
       * Why compare HashSets here?  Just so that the order of the
       * elements in the list is not important for this test.
       */
      assertEquals(new HashSet<>(expected),
         new HashSet<>(ExampleMap.highScoringStudents(
            courseListsByStudent, 85)));
   }
```

I've tried different if statements but I've always only been able to either add the student who is under the score threshold or only all 3.

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `boolean` flag to store whether or not the student has a higher grade than the threshold in ALL courses.

```java
boolean pass = true;
for (CourseGrade courses : course_grades) 
    if (courses.getScore() <= scoreThreshold) {
        pass = false;
        break;
    }
if (pass) highScoringStudents.add(current.getKey());
```

This can be written more concisely using `Stream`s.

```java
return scoresByApplicantName.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().stream()
          .allMatch(course -> course.getScore() > scoreThreshold))
          .map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: thank you so much! that's exactly what i was missing